# Is it possible to exclude i386 arch when building for generic ios simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I currently have a CI/CD pipeline for running automated tests using appium. However, due to various reasons, the building of the application and the testing of the application is segregated into two different process.

During the build process, a generic-simulator app will be built using `generic/platform=iOS Simulator` as destination.

Then when that is done, the artifact will be sent out to be tested on different simulators.

The issue now is that I recently included a framework which does not support i386 architecture. So now the generic build process is failing, producing an error output of `missing required architecture i386 in file ...`

I'm wondering is there a way to dictate in xcodebuild's destination, to build for a generic simulator destination, but without i386 support.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best solution out there, but I found a way to circumvent this issue for now.

The way I use the library is already via a wrapper class, so the only thing I did was to ensure implementation of the concrete class is wrapped with conditional compilation, something like so

```
import ProblemFramework

Protocol IA {
    func doSomething(_ completion: CompletionBlock)
}

Class A: Protocol IA {
     #if arch(arm64) || arch(x86_64)
     func doSomething(_ completion: CompletionBlock) {
          //call problem framework
     }
     #else
     func doSomething(_ completion: CompletionBlock) {
         //failsafe or workaround
     }
     #endif
}
```

But if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears